# How to redirect logged in user to the same page using spring security?

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I have implemented my website using spring security.

I have added default-target-url in form-login tag:

```
<security:form-login login-page="/pages/dashboard.action" default-target-url="/welcome.action" authentication-failure-url="/pages/dashboard.action?error=true" />
```

So when ever user successfully logs in it will be redirected to the page which is defined by mapping given in default-target-url.

But I dont want this, I have log-in button at many places and i want user to directed to the same page from where he is logging in.

Can any one help me with this?

my dispather-servlet.xml:

```
<security:http  use-expressions="true">  
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/IGG/citizen/*" access="hasRole('IGG_CITIZEN')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/pages/dashboard.action" default-target-url="/welcome.action" authentication-failure-url="/pages/dashboard.action?error=true" />  
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/pages/dashboard.action" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" /> 
    <security:anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_GUEST"/>  
    <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/pages/dashboard.action"/>
    <security:remember-me/>  
    <security:access-denied-handler delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
</security:http>
```

Comment: So remove `default-target-url`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bean SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler as your success handler:

```
<bean id="successHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/welcome.action"/>
</bean>
```

And refer to it from the form-login using authentication-success-handler-ref parameter:

```
<security:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler"/>
```

The SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler uses page which user tried to access before initialization of the authentication process as the default landing page. When it's not available the defaultTargetUrl is used instead. The "stored page" value is set inside ExceptionTranslationFilter.